# How to integrate Node.js running on different port with Vue.js running on a different port altogether?

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, cors, frontend

I have a local Node.js server running on port 3000. I have another dev server for front end using webpack, running on 8080. Node is connected to MySQL server. I want to send data from my Node to front end. My project structure looks like this:-

```
SampleProject
 -> BackEnd
 -> FrontEnd
```

Should I use CORS node module? If not how should I send the data?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be to use webpack-dev-server [proxy](https://webpack.github.io/docs/webpack-dev-server.html#proxy) option to proxy requests from webpack-dev-server (8080) to Node (3000).

Example config:

```
{
  devServer: {
    proxy: {
      '/api': {
        target: 'http://127.0.0.1:3000'
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I have updated my question here. Could you answer it? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45553748/passing-data-from-node-to-vuejs/45554207#45554207